# Blocking multiple login sessions with Amazon Cognito Identity js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Amazon Cognito currently allows multiple logins by issuing different validated tokens to each login sessions.

However, what if I were to only allow one session at a time?

Can't seem to find anything like it in the Amazon-Cognito-Identity documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature by default with Cognito User Pools. However, have you looked into using the pre and post authentication triggers that Cognito provides to store the fact that the user authenticated or the time he had authenticated at? You can then block requests in the pre authentication trigger if the user is already authenticated somewhere else.

Comment: It doesn't look to me like you can maintain your own list of users with active sessions since there is no trigger for sign out. Would you call the `getUser` method on the identity pool to see if the user is logged in? If so, how do you get the access token for a specific user (e.g. by email) in the pre authentication trigger?